# Caching to make my website offline isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, caching

Below is my cache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2013-11-22 14:38:54735779

CACHE:

../../../../assets/img/background_01.jpg
../../../../assets/img/background_02.jpg
../../../../assets/img/background_03.jpg
../../../../assets/img/datepicker_icon.png
../../../../assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
../../../../assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js
../../../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
../../../../offline/offline.js
../../../../offline/offline_external.js

NETWORK:
*
```

In Google Chrome (while internet is active), I am able to see that all the above specified files are cached. Google Chrome is able to show the items that are cached. However, when I try switching off internet and refreshing the page, chrome reports the following errors:

> Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (-1)   Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   (anonymous function) GET
>   http://mywebsite.com/app/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

The path to Jquery is correct and I am not able to fault that as I am able to click the link and it navigates me to the right location in the server.

Can someone tell me where I have made an error?

I tried the same setting in my local server and it works without error.

My .htaccess setting is this:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest manifest
AddType application/octet-stream csv
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.myswebsite\.com$ [NC]
```

Please note that I have tried the

> AddType text/cache-manifest manifest

and

> AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

It does not solve the issue. When I refresh the page when the internet is down, the offline still does not work.

Comment: On your page how are you referencing jquery? Are you using a relative path or absolute?

Answer (score 1):

You should make all the assets start with the / relative to the base domain, your file should look like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2013-11-22 14:38:54735779

CACHE:

/assets/img/background_01.jpg
/assets/img/background_02.jpg
/assets/img/background_03.jpg
/assets/img/datepicker_icon.png
/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js
/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
/offline/offline.js
/offline/offline_external.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution to this issue but I was experiencing the same. It turns out that I was trying to access a javascript resource before it was loaded.

I solved the issue by ensuring that accessing of the javascript resource was below the reference to the javascript file on the page and I also wrapped it in a "$(document).ready(function () {})" call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // access the resource here..
})
```

This appeared to sort the problem for me. I'm not quite sure why the page was more "forgiving" in online mode.